# $ord_R(f(x))$ Ring Additive Order

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

For a ring $R$, $a\in R$ and $n \in\mathbb{N}$, we say $a$ has additive order $n$ 
if $$ \underbrace{a+a+\dots+a}_\text{$n$}  =0_R $$ and for $m<n$  we have $\underbrace{a+a+\dots+a}_\text{$m$}  \neq 0_R$. We write $\text{ord}_R(a)=n$.

Assume every element of $R$ has an order (not neessarily the same one)

Prove that every element of $R[x]$ has an order

---

**Attempt**

$f(x) \in R(x)$ where 
$$ f(x)=a_0+a_1x+\dots+a_n x^n$$
each $a_i$ where $i\in[0,n]$ has an order
$$\text{ord}_R(a_0)=n_0 ,\dots, \text{ord}(a_n)=n_n$$
$\text{Lcm}(n_0,\dots,n_n) $ is the $\text{ord}_R(f(x))$

*missing something?*

Comment: Missed to show why the $ord_R(f(x))$ works. It can be easily done.

Comment: I am sorry I was wrong. I didn't read properly. Your proof looks correct.